# display default path in address bar

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I want to route these 3 paths to default path.

```
www.mysite.com/page1.aspx
www.mysite.com/page2.aspx
www.mysite.com/page3.aspx
```

I want to appear these 3 pages in address bar like this: www.mysite.com

There are only these 3 pages in my asp.net project.

How can I do this in asp.net 3.5 with IIS 6.0.

Comment: 'www.mysite.com/' is not a valid virtual path.

Comment: "/" would be the correct virtual path for the root of the website I think...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL rewriting module or write a custom httphandler as demonstrated here:

http://bit.ly/fkBNlA

URL Rewriters:

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite 
http://urlrewriter.net/